# Missing properties in GET users/lookup Twitter API call via python-twitter

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm using this Twitter API call: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup

**The example results show that a 'verified' property should be returned.**

Via python-twitter `UsersLookup` method:
https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='XXX',          consumer_secret='XXX',                      access_token_key='XXX',                   access_token_secret='XXX')
followers = api.UsersLookup([XXX], None, None, True)
for x in followers:
    print x
```

The 'XXX' are filled out appropriately.  The return data I get does not include the 'verified' property among others that the Twitter Dev documentation says it should.

1. Did this function change and Twitter documentation didn't update?
2. Is python-twitter eating some returned values?
3. Is my print out method ignoring incoming data?

Answer (score 0):

The 'verified' field and possibly others do not return unless their value is True.  This seems inconsistent given that other similar Twitter API calls return the property field regardless of True or False value.